# Loop steps in karate UI automation based on size

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have a karate UI feature file

Issue:-
In the file i have a step where there are n addresses and based on clicking each address i move forward to the next page/action.

I want to do this dynamically where i go into a url http://xxx.xxx.com and in that url on the next page there are 3 addresses listed among which one can be selected and then a button needs clicking to go to next page

```
And match temp.text contains 'Choose an address'

And karate.sizeOf(locateAll("//div[@class='addr-name']"))
```

where the step locate all will give the size of the number of addresses listed on the page and then

```
And locateAll('.loc-name')[2].click()
```

based on the address location on the page viz., 1,2 or 3 i need to select it and do other actions.
However i am unable to get to do this dynamically.

I used js in karate UI so that i take the size in a for loop and execute the rest of the steps inside it viz.,

```
And def myfunc =
      """
        function(arg){
          for(var i = 1; i <= arg; i++){
             karate.locateAll('.addr-name')[i].click()
             karate.click("//button[@class='btn-submit loc-order']")
             karate.refresh()
             karate.waitForText('body', 'Home')
                         
             }
            }
```

However it doesnt work and throws exception that

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (locateAll) on com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioBridge@27e32fe4 failed due to: Unknown identifier: locateAll
- <js>.:anonymous(Unnamed:3)
```

I am totally at a loss.Any idea as to what i am missing here?